# Is it possible to generate HTML file from tkinter code?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I undertand tkinter generate native OS application, but out of curiosity I am looking if it can generate a HTML file binding so that I can open and see the result in a browser.

Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: I doubt it (but I'm happy to be proven wrong)

Comment: I'm with @byxor here, but as an alternative to tkinter maybe you could use https://github.com/smoqadam/PyFladesk ?